# Is there autoexpect for Perl's Expect?

Tags: perl, expect, autoexpect

I would like to generate Perl [`Expect`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Expect) code automatically, does something like [`autoexpect`](http://expect.nist.gov/example/autoexpect.man.html) exist for Perl's `Expect`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a good answer, but will have to do until a good answer comes along.

I ran the TCL autoexpect and it created a script file, I then wrote couple lines of perl code that parses the lines with  "send" and "expect" tags and then uses the perl expect module to run them along with some other actions.

This hybrid approach gets me by, but I am still hoping for a better answer to come.